# Rows inside an Ionic footer don't stack properly

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have the following markup, which should result in the input being stacked above the row of icons. Alas, they each take up half the width of the footer. I've spent way too much time trying to find the culprit CSS related to the footer, but have come up short.

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced auto-height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-twitter"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-facebook"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-linkedin-outline"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-googleplus"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3cjrjfrx/)**

I'd be interested in either a fix for what appears to be a bug in Ionic's grid, or an override solution to make the rows behave. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the input's div and the buttons' div, then give the input's div the class `bar-subfooter` instead of `bar-footer`, and give the buttons' div the classes `bar bar-footer`:

```
<div class="bar bar-subfooter bar-balanced auto-height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bar bar-footer row">
    <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-twitter"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-facebook"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-linkedin-outline"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-social-googleplus"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad. While this doesn't address the core issue of the misbehaving rows, I'm glad to learn of subfooters. I hadn't encountered that in the docs to date. +1 for now.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the subheader has a particular bottom position, which doesn't accommodate more footer content.

Comment: I'm a bit confused—when I apply the change I suggested I get [this](http://oi58.tinypic.com/9zwnd4.jpg), which I thought was what you were looking for, since the input is stacked above the buttons. I must be misunderstanding you though.

Comment: I can't see your image. Please modify the Fiddle demo I provided and link it.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/t63akgr7/) is a fork. Fiddle has been behaving strangely—earlier, if I edited and updated your demo, I got one result, and if I then forked it, I got a different one. This does highlight a nice thing about screencaps; they can overcome eccentricities in environments. [This](http://hush.es/content/ionic_stack_answer.jpg) is what I saw when I edited yours, and [this](http://hush.es/content/ionic_stack_answer_forked.jpg) is what I saw when I forked it, in case my fork looks weird to you.